# Do the Shuttle/ISS EMU suits have model numbers?

Tags: iss, space-shuttle, spacesuits

Early NASA spacesuits were given model numbers, as described in slide 3 of this [NASA Powerpoint](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140005150).  The model numbers were assigned in the format *`P-#M`*, where

- the first letter (*`P`*) describes the program (`G` = Gemini, `A` = Apollo).
- an optional second letter `X` describes an experimental model.
- the number (*`#`*) after the dash describes the iteration of the development sequence, starting with `1`.
- the final letter (*`M`*) describes the manufacturer.

Thus some notable suits were

- the [Mercury suits](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140013477) were just called "Mark IV" and were numbered with the mission (e.g. Shepard was `MR-3`).
- the `G`emini suits, made by the David `C`lark Company, were `G-3C` and `G-4C`.
- the `A`pollo suits, made by International `L`atex Corp., were `A-7L`.

---

The [Extravehicular Mobility Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extravehicular_Mobility_Unit) has been used for spacewalks from the Space Shuttle and International Space Station.  **Does the EMU have model numbers?**  How are the model numbers formatted, and what are some notable models?

Comment: I went to all of those Spacesuit Knowledge Capture briefings that I possibly get to, they were awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The EMU suits with a Primary life support system (PLSS) have serial numbers, see table 3 at page 20 of this [NASA spacesuit audit](https://oig.nasa.gov/docs/IG-17-018.pdf)

The 18 EMUs produced have serial numbers running from 3001 to 3018, with EMU 3003, 3006, 3008 and 3010 currently onboard the ISS (as of 2017).

Comment: "The EMU suits with a Primary life support system (PLSS)" What other kind of EMU suits are there?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have no idea, but since that was specifically noted, I kept it. Perhaps the PLSS itself is what gets serial numbers?

Comment: Could be. Most of the suit parts are mix-n-match.

Comment: Not sure serial # = model # either.